# Tests injecting beans with @Autowired annotations

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I want to write unit test using Junit and Mockito, in this case I don't want to write integration tests. The method that I want to test uses variables that are injected via Spring using the @Value or @Autowired annotations. How can I populate the injected variables so that when I run a test they are not null. Before days of annotations I would have created mocked classes of the variables and set them via setter methods.

I'm writing unit tests so I would prefer not to use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MockitoJUnitRunner`.

```
class SystemUnderTest {
    @Autowired
    private Dependency dep;

    // ...
}
```

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourTest {
    @Mock
    private Dependency mockDependency;

    @InjectMocks
    private SystemUnderTest testee;

    @Test
    public void testSystem() {
        // at this point testee is already injected with mockDependency
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the `SutsDependency` referring to?

Comment: Whoops, fixed; this was supposed to mean "SUT's dependency" but then I thought it wouldn't add much but forgot to change all occurences.